# Grouped Sum on complicated calculated fields in other column

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with data (Sheet1). First number is a secuencial number representing a number of month.

Sheet1 <month, year, data1, data2>
[first row: titles]
1 1 data11 data12
2 1 data21 data22
3 1 data31 data32
4 1 data41 data42
5 1 data51 data52
6 1 data61 data62
7 1 data71 data72
8 1 data81 data82
9 1 data91 data92
10 1 data101 data102
11 1 data111 data112
12 1 data121 data122
13 2 data131 data132
14 2 data141 data142

Sheet2

[month, year, formule]

1 1 sheet1!C2-3*sheet1!B1

2 1 sheet1!C3-3*sheet1!B2

3 1 sheet1!C4-3*sheet1!B3

4 1 sheet1!C5-3*sheet1!B4

5 1 sheet1!C6-3*sheet1!B5

6 1 sheet1!C7-3*sheet1!B6

7 1 sheet1!C8-3*sheet1!B7

8 1 sheet1!C9-3*sheet1!B8

9 1 sheet1!C10-3*sheet1!B9

10 1 sheet1!C11-3*sheet1!B10

11 1 sheet1!C12-3*sheet1!B11

12 1 sheet1!C13-3*sheet1!B12

13 2 sheet1!C14-3*sheet1!B13

14 2 sheet1!C15-3*sheet1!B114

Sheet3
[year, Sum of column C in sheet2 grouped by year]

Firts row <year,formule>

1 =SUMIF(sheet2!B$2:B$15, A2, sheet!C$2:C$15)

2 =SUMIF(sheet2!B$2:B$15, A3, sheet!C$2:C$15)

My question, Can I remove and do the calculation in Sheet3
I can if the column C of sheet2 is moved to sheet1 but I don't want to put many columns in sheet1 because Sheet2 has many columns. If we can remove Sheet2, we removing a lot of formula (in this example 14 + 2 formules -> only 2 formules)

Thanks

Comment: What advantage do you expect from using OFFSET(Sheet1!$AL2,0,0) instead of plain Sheet1!$AL2?

Comment: Frankly, I would doubt the result of `=23+54+86*34+(45-13)/(1-0.66)*8` because of the haphazard way of inserting parentheses. (I created this formula by replacing your references with random numbers.) But to answer your question, it doesn't matter whether the cells you reference contain hard numbers or formulas. Any mistakes in the result would be caused by the setting of parenthesis, not the origin of the numbers.

Comment: If I have 10 similar Indicators with vars x1, x2, x3, x4, ..., x10 in ten consecutive columns, I Know that first formule is with OFFSET(*,0,0), second formule is with OFFSET(*,0,1), and so on. I don't need to check all the formulas.

Comment: This sounds as if there will almost certainly be a way of doing what you want, i.e. omitting sheet 2. However, to enable a specific suggested answer please post some more sample data and formulas from each sheet in a way that we can reproduce what you are currently seeing.

Comment: Hi, Ed. I have created an excel example with Sheets Data, MonthlyData (1269 Formules), YearlyData (102 formules). If I can go from Data to YearlyData Directly then I can go from 1269+102 formules to only 102 formules.

I put the file (64KB) in the dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6ve0bgmktd0j6s/Example.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The year is in column 2 then

=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!B$2:B$424=Sheet3!B2)*(Formula using $2:$424 in each column of the mensual formula))